# Can't Attach google managed certificate with my GKE ingress load balancer

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, gke-networking

## managed-cert.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: managed-cert-ssl
spec:
  domains:
    - apis.binarybunon.com
```

## ingress-srv.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-srv
  annotations:
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
        # External Load Balancer

    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: my-apis-zone
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: managed-cert-ssl
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"


spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: apis.binarybunon.com
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /api/user/?(.*)
            backend:
              service:
                name: customer-api-srv
                port:
                  number: 5001
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /api/administration/?(.*)
            backend:
              service:
                name : admin-api-srv
                port:
                  number: 5000
```

## Certificate details in Load Balancer

[Certificate details in Load Balancer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9P2Q.png)

## The Problem is it says (In use by : None) in Certificate Details. and my ssl is now working in my domain .

## Note : HTTP routes is working fine. and i can access pod and and my app with http

Comment: you dont have ssl cert yet check the status it still provisioning it takes 30 min around to get certs, but looks like your domain is not visible so might could be failing.

Comment: I tried. this since last 10 days . some of my ssl cert is bing provisioning 2 or 3 days.

Comment: Does the domain apis.binarybunon.com resolves to the same IP address you have in the annotation  kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name ?

This is how our cert manager verifies the ownership of the domain

Comment: Yes . i checked it . and it resolve the same ip address .